# Can't fit tabular onto page

Tags: tables

```
\documentclass{article}
    \begin{document} 
       \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}
            DEC&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15\\
                 \hline
            BIN&0000&0001&0010&0011&0100&0101&0110&0111&1000&1001&1010&1011&1100&1101&1110&1111\\
                 \hline
            HEX&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&A&B&C&D&E&F
        \end{tabular}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

[image: resize text not working]

Comment: Have a look if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/332902/my-table-doesnt-fit-what-are-my-options can help.

Comment: if yiu use tabularx you need X columns (always) but I would not use tabularx for a data table that has no linebreaking just use tabular and perhas `\small`  before it (impossible to say as you have provided no information about your page or font sizes)

Comment: Please don't show images as code. Instead add a [short, but compilable test file](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) as text to your question which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a `document` environment.

Comment: You might get away with decreasing the tabcolsep, as shown in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332903/36296

Comment: Now the syntax with `\begin{tabular}{\textwidth}{...}` is just wrong.

Comment: The number of `c`'s does not match the number of your columns. You should get an error about this.

Comment: FFS! Well, that's a dumb mistake! 

Thank you,  samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz

Correct number og 'c's fixed the problem.

Comment: @AlexMadsen Moral of the story: never ignore error messages! The log file would have told you `! Extra alignment tab has been changed to \cr.`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- you need to specify as many columns `c` as your table has columns. In your example, two were missing
- you could decrease the `tabcolsep` a bit to make your table more compact (this is explained in more detail in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/332903/36296)

---

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document} 

\begingroup
  \scriptsize
  \setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
  \begin{tabular}{|*{17}{c|}}
      DEC&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&10&11&12&13&14&15\\
           \hline
      BIN&0000&0001&0010&0011&0100&0101&0110&0111&1000&1001&1010&1011&1100&1101&1110&1111\\
           \hline
      HEX&0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8&9&A&B&C&D&E&F
  \end{tabular}
\endgroup
    
\end{document}
```